# Add Checkboxes to a views listing of titles

Tags: views, forms

I am looking to pull in a views listing of events by title into a entity form.

I need help figuring out how to add checkboxes to the views listing of title. This way if someone checks the box when the form submits it will show in the form submitted information that they are interested in that event. Then I need to add that listing to the form.

Thanks

Comment: Have you lookup https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations ?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done. You have to build a view -> Entity view and pull in your fields.
Then in the form create a field -> Entity Reference -> Check boxes/radio buttons -- under Entity selection -> Views: Filter by an entity reference view -- then pull in the view you created.

Easy Peesy when you figure it out.